# Which system file stores the information displayed by the "net user Administrator" command in Windows 7?

Tags: windows, forensics, windows-7

Which system file stores the information displayed by the "net user Administrator" command in Windows 7? Need to find the details of the users in a dead Windows 7 machine.

Details of the command is [here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2012-r2-and-2012/cc771865%28v%3Dws.11%29).

**Edit:**

I have been informed by @Moab that specific user info is stored in each user account folder in the NTUSER.DAT file. However, in my case, the administrator account has never been logged on and it does not have a user account folder.

Comment: I assume it is stored in the same place as user passwords, the Windows registry.

Comment: @Moab what is that location?

Comment: See this....https://www.thewindowsclub.com/where-are-the-windows-registry-files-located-in-windows-7

Comment: There is also specific user info stored in each users account folder in the NTUSER.DAT file.  C:\Users\<User name>\ntuser.dat

Answer (score 0):

If You were within Active Directory environment, I would say to start with analyzing **ntds.dit**. But since You are in probably desktop machine, I suggest to look around SAM/SYSTEM/SOFTWARE registry files, which might store informations like the one You need (like user creation date)